# Ruby syntax confusion brackets and hash

Tags: ruby, syntax, brackets

Objective: Use the .each method on the odds array to print out double the value of each item of the array. In other words, multiply each item by 2.

Make sure to use print rather than puts, so your output appears on one line.

```
code:

odds = [1,3,5,7,9]

odds.each do |x|
    x *= 2 
    print "#{x}"
end
```

Doing this exercise on Codecademy, I'm rather confused about the syntax as why there needs to be a #{} surrounding the x and why can't it just be: print "x" or print #x".  What are the roles of the hash and brackets? It perplexes me as why ruby doesn't print out "#{X}" rather than the "x" number multiplied by 2 due to it being surrounded by quotation marks? Previous exercises also featured both hashes and curly brackets #{user_input} where the console printed whatever we typed rather than print out "#{user input}" itself.

Comment: a "hashtag" is not a symbol.   It's a twitter semantic meaning not existing in ruby.

Comment: `odds.each { |x| puts x * 2 }` works perfectly fine. There is no need for string interpolation at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `print "x"` and expect it prints the value of the `x` object. What if you wanted to print the x letter? So, we need interpolation for that. 
But interpolation used in that way has just the collateral effect to make `x`a string. You can do the same without interpolation:

`print x`

Anyway, I'd probably do

```
odds = [1,3,5,7,9]
odds.each { |x| print x * 2 }
```

About interpolation: you can use it when you should concatenate several strings and it would be ugly. For instance

```
puts name + " " + surname
puts "#{name} #{surname}"
```

I prefer the latter